# React Redux props is always udefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

User is always udefined. React + Redux. This is my first day using Redux. This is my reducer.

```
const initialState = {
    user: 'User'
}

export function auth(state = initialState, action: any) {
    const {type, payload} = action;

    switch (type) {
        case "REGISTER_SUCCESS":
            return {
                ...state,
                user: payload.user,
            };
        case "REGISTER_FAIL":
            return {
                ...state,
                user: null,
            };
        case "LOGIN_SUCCESS":
            return {
                ...state,
                user: payload.user,
            };
        case "LOGIN_FAIL":
            return {
                ...state,
                user: null,
            };
        case "LOGOUT":
            return {
                ...state,
                user: null,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

console.log always return "User {user: undefined, dispatch: ƒ}". Although he seems to have to output something anyway. This is my Sign In component.

```
import React, {SyntheticEvent, useState} from 'react';
import {Password} from "../../../ui/input/password/password";
import {Button} from "../../../ui/button/button";
import {Input} from '../../../ui/input/input';
import {Text} from "../../../ui/text/text";
import {NavLink} from "react-router-dom";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {login as onHandleLogin} from "../../../core/redux/actions/auth";
import {useDispatch} from "react-redux";

function SignInForm(props: any)  {
    const [login, setLogin] = useState<string>("")
    const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>("")
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    function onHandleSubmit(e: SyntheticEvent) {
        e.preventDefault()

        dispatch(onHandleLogin(login, password))
    }

    function onHandleCheck() {
        return !(login && password)
    }

    console.log('User', props)

    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={onHandleSubmit}>
                <h1>Sign In</h1>
                <Input setValue={setLogin} value={login} label="Login"/>
                <Password
                    label="Password"
                    setValue={setPassword}
                    value={password}
                />
                <Button disabled={onHandleCheck()} text="Sign In"/>
                <Text>Not a member yet? <NavLink to="/register">Sign up</NavLink></Text>
            </form>
            <span>User: {props.user}</span>
        </>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: { user: any; }) => {
    return {
        user: state.user
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SignInForm)
```

As I said, this is my first encounter with Redux. I will be glad for any help. TY)

**EDIT**

roodReducer:

```
import {combineReducers} from "redux";
import {auth} from "./reducers/auth";

export default combineReducers({
    auth,
})
```

Comment: Can you show the code where `SignInForm` is used? From the symptoms you describe it looks like it's not getting expected props.

Comment: @tromgy props come from Redux - you can see this because the Component is wrapped in a Redux HoC at the bottom of the file where it says `export default`.

Comment: Could you add your rootReducer file as I think you have used auth Reducer in the rootReducer and in SignIn component you are directly accessing state.user. Another alternative for debugging is to console the value of state in the mapStateToProps

Comment: Just use `const {user} = useSelector(state => state.auth)`. Then print it out. It will work

Comment: if you are using the latest version of react, check useSelector hooks in react redux

Comment: @Erick, I added, but I don't think the problem is in rootReducer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is a small implementation of your scenario. The code uses connect HOC to fetch data from redux.

Note: The commented code is the one that uses useSelector. Feel free to use the either of the two
Please refer to the code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8ivxam

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This is the first time I encounter this and it is still difficult for me)

Comment: @КристианЧайковский you can use the sample code and try it out on your end. Thanks